# Basic build issue regarding libs, pkg-config and opencv

Tags: linux, opencv, g++

I have successfully built and installed the opencv lib. Now I am trying to use these libs in my application but I keep getting link errors. I am using:

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

When I run this on the command line I can see the output. It list a lot of libraries but not all of them are listed with the absolute path specified. For example, here is a partial output:

```
libippcc_l.a libippvm_l.a tbb rt pthread m dl /usr/lib/libXext.s stdc++
```

And when I build my app I get link errors. Here is a partial output:

```
g++: libipps_l.a: No such file or directory
g++: libippi_l.a: No such file or directory
g++: libippcv_l.a: No such file or directory
g++: libippcc_l.a: No such file or directory
g++: libippvm_l.a: No such file or directory
g++: tbb: No such file or directory
g++: rt: No such file or directory
g++: pthread: No such file or directory
g++: m: No such file or directory
g++: dl: No such file or directory
g++: stdc++: No such file or directory
```

It appears that the linker cannot resolve the libraries that do not include an absolute path which seems reasonable. But my confusion is why dosn't the output from pkg-config include the absolute path for all of its libs?  When I do NOT use "pkg-config --libs opencv" on the build line, the libraries for intel ipp, pthread, m, stdc++, etc gets resolved properly and the app builds fine because I also have them specified on the link line as: "-lpthread -lstdc++"  ... etc.  These are positioned on the link line AFTER the I specify: "pkg --libs opencv"

But using "pkg-config --libs opencv" screws up the resolution.

I have run "ldconfig" from the command line to update all of the symbolic links in my libs directories but this did not resolve this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feel tempted to change the title... but I won't.

Comment: sorry about the title. I am new here and am just learning what is proper behavior. I just get some what frustrated when build problems get in the way of progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pkg-config --libs opencv` is outputting that, then you have a problem. Maybe a previous installation of OpenCV broke it, or maybe you are not using a version recent enough, or maybe it wasn't compiled successfully, or maybe there's a problem with the newest version from the repository.

Anyway, I'm using OpenCV 2.3.1 on Mac OS X and `pkg-config --libs opencv` outputs the following info:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

You can try to compile your application by hand to see if anything else is broken:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann
```

Note that your install might have placed OpenCV headers and libraries in different directories.

Comment: thanks for your help. I will go back to square one and rebuild opencv. Just knowing that pkg-config should output the 'l' in front of the library name helps. So I can fix low level issues first before moving on.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [how I did it with v2.4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10440832/176769).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem may be related to the one I'm having, and the subject of this [pull request](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/1615) to opencv.  My guess is: you are installing from source on a linux machine?  Does your situation change if you find your `opencv.pc` file (probably at /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc), and add `-l` before the offending words there (rt pthread etc)?

NB: Installing from source will make a new (bad) opencv.pc that overwrites the one where you made the changes I'm suggesting, so if you go through more rebuild-install cycles, do remember to go fix up opencv.pc again before trying to rebuild your program.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused - usually in my practice - by new CMake or a misbehaving one :) It's quite simple to solve - edit by hand opencv.pc and add missing "-l" prefixes to the names. That's it! All other problems are disappearing after this fix. Second usual trouble is the PKG_CONFIG_PATH itself - add it in your shell GLOBAL(!!) profile script and re-launch the shell and verify it via printenv command or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for "opencv.pc" to find the path. For me, the package was in

```
/Applications/opencv-2.4.11/build/unix-install/
```

Thus, for me the command that worked was:

```
pkg-config --libs /Applications/opencv-2.4.11/build/unix-install/opencv.pc
```