# checking libraries and compiling in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I typed in this command to check what libraries are installed in opencv,

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

I got the following output:

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.s
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_feature2d.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

What is the appropraite command I should give in order to compile a file that reads a video from file?

I've tried using `g++ -I/usr/include/opencv -lxcore -lhighgui -lm nameoffile.cpp`
but I keep getting the error, `/usr/lib/ld cannot find -lxcore etc...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Basic build issue regarding libs, pkg-config and opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526124/basic-build-issue-regarding-libs-pkg-config-and-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use `pkg-config --cflags --libs libname`
then you can write somthing like this

```
g++ -I/usr/include/opencv -lxcore -lhighgui -lm nameoffile.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

that way you can include the paths to the libs you want to link

Comment: I've tried that and the compiler says "-libs: unknown option"

Comment: sry there should be a double `-` my mistake

Comment: ok done that. Another question though. When u say "that way I can include the paths to the libs i want to link", what do u mean? sorry very new to opencv and have to use it for a project. what would I put in place of 'libname'?

Comment: lets say you add `-lhighgui` then you would add a `--libs highgui`
the pkg-config command returns somthing with `-L /some/path/to/the/lib` and also some `-lsomelibs` which will be needed to link this lib this also includes libs witch will be needed for the wanted lib