# Compilation error in OpenCV3 when Not using imshow()

Tags: c++, opencv

I have following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  Mat A = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << -3,-2,-1,  0,1,2,   3,4,5);
  imshow("aa", A);
  waitKey(0);
  cout << "A = " << endl << " " << A << endl << endl;
  Mat B;
  threshold(A, B, 0, 255, THRESH_TOZERO);
  cout << "B = " << endl << " " << B << endl << endl;
}
```

Which is compiling fine. And I am compiling as follows:
    g++ a.cpp `pkg-config opencv --libs` `pkg-config opencv --cflags`

But when I commented two line it's giving compilation errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  Mat A = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << -3,-2,-1,  0,1,2,   3,4,5);
  // imshow("aa", A);
  // waitKey(0);
  cout << "A = " << endl << " " << A << endl << endl;
  Mat B;
  threshold(A, B, 0, 255, THRESH_TOZERO);
  cout << "B = " << endl << " " << B << endl << endl;
}
```

As follows:

```
...../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: undefined reference to `m7_ippiFilterSobelVertBorder_32f_C1R'
...../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: undefined reference to `n8_ippiFilterSobelNegVertBorder_32f_C1R'
...../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: undefined reference to `k0_ippiFilterSobelVertBorder_32f_C1R'
...../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: undefined reference to `mx_ippiFilterSobelVertBorder_8u16s_C1R'
...../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: undefined reference to `y8_ippiFilterSobelHorizBorder_32f_C1R'
...../opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so: undefined reference to `e9_ippiFilterSobelVertBorder_32f_C1R'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic build issue regarding libs, pkg-config and opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526124/basic-build-issue-regarding-libs-pkg-config-and-opencv)

Comment: you gotta include ipp

Comment: But in the initial program, it was working. And this error is coming only when I am commenting two lines...